# what is .src in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, src

What is `.src` in the JavaScript code below?

```js
function jsDropDown(imgid,folder,newimg) {
    document.getElementById(imgid).src="http://www.cookwithbetty.com/" + folder + "/" + newimg + ".gif";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the [`src` DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/src) of the `<img>` element that it's dealing with.

Comment: so, what the function and why can it use in javascript?

Comment: @dramasea - I don't follow the question, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: you are simply setting an element's property like you would with any property, in this case src is the source of an image. But as everyone said, it is simply a specific dom property that you can access. "src" is not a function but a property name of the object "img"

Comment: so the above function is to grab the following image with id imgid and change the source to source that specify?Thanks

Comment: @dramasea - yup, that's *exactly* what it's doing :)

Comment: any more something like .height , .width, .src that we can use in javascript that we can change the property of specified element? Any resources on that?And what we call that?Thanks!!

Comment: @dramasea - yup, google and MDC (or the W3c spec directly) are the best resources here, here's a full list for image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/image

Answer (score 1):

It maps onto the [src attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-src-IMG) of the img element. (Although this is [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-17701901) rather than JS)

Answer (score 0):

`src` is the property of `<img>` tag and can be accessed by javascript to assing the image url

Answer (score -2):

**src** is in computer programming, a common abbreviation for **source code**.